# I don't get what ''元気よくとはいかない'' means

Tags: meaning, translation, usage, syntax, particle-と

''~とりあえず、新学期。まぁさ、元気よくとはいかないけど、でもこんな天気もいいし、桜も咲いてるし、もう少しだけ愛想が良くてもいいんじゃないかしら？''

What はいかない is? is it like てはいけない (must not/don't have to)? If so, why はいけない and not はいかない?

Could you break '''元気よくとはいかない'' down?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

いかない is the negative-form of 行く, and いけない is the negative-potential-form of 行く. Both have a number of special usages when written in hiragana.

Here, ～とはいかない means "won't go like ～", and it's a way to say something won't go/proceed/happen as expected. This と is a quotative-like-と, and this は is a topic/contrast marker. とはいかない and てはいけない are different:

- 元気よくとはいかないけど
  (literally) although it may not go like "Cheerfully!"
  → if not cheerfully in particular
- 元気よくてはいけないけど
  although you must not to be cheerful

Examples:

- すぐにとはいかないよ。
  Not right now, you know.
- これで完成とはいきません。
  (Unfortunately) This doesn't make it complete yet.